# How to use CTRL+D to end input?

Tags: bash, shell, key, keycode

I'm trying to write a short shell script that lets me input a bunch of numbers, each followed by ENTER, and then use CTRL+D to stop taking input and to print the sum of the inputted numbers.

The result I'm looking for is something like this:

> sum.sh
>
> 1 [ENTER]
>
> 5 [ENTER]
>
> 8 [ENTER]
>
> [CTRL+D]
>
> 14

I have a vague idea that I can do this using *read* and keycodes, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `read -r VARNAME` for that, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

sum=0
while read -r n; do
    ((sum += n))
done
echo "$sum"
```

Comment: *VARNAME* is optional (`n` in your example).  `REPLY` is the default variable.